# Issues converting image to Data URI Base64

Tags: javascript, base64, data-uri

I'm trying to convert an image located on a server to a Data URI. When I pass through the exact url location it converts fine. I need to be able to pass through the filename as a variable however when I do it returns with a base64 for data:text/html not data:image/jpeg.

Any help is appreciated!

```
    function toDataURL(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}

//Works Here
    toDataURL(`/attachments/HouseLandPackage/FloorPlans/Floorplan.jpg`, function(dataUrl) {
            UserSelection.FloorPlanBase64 = dataUrl;
        });

//Doesn't work here (Floorplan = Floorplan.jpg in this)
    toDataURL(`/attachments/HouseLandPackage/FloorPlans/${Floorplan}`, function(dataUrl) {
                UserSelection.FloorPlanBase64 = dataUrl;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
toDataURL(`/attachments/HouseLandPackage/FloorPlans/${Floorplan}`, function(dataUrl) {
                UserSelection.FloorPlanBase64 = dataUrl;
            });
```

You should use `${variableName}` instead of just `{variableName}` with backticks

Comment: Apologies! I meant that in my question, amended it now.